# Performing queries filtering on Oracle's side or in the application itself

Tags: java, oracle, performance, eclipselink

We're using *EclipseLink* with Oracle. I have a performance question.
In which cases should we prefer to do the filtering on Oracle's side, and in which cases should we do the filtering in the application itself?

For example, let's say I want to retrieve all the not-deleted-items. 
Is it better, performance-wise, to create a SQL/JPQL query to retrieve **not deleted** items, or should I retrieve **all** the items from DB and filter them in the code itself?

And of course there are more complicated queries.

Thanks.

Comment: Have your SQL query return only the data you need.

Comment: This is application/use case dependent. You can't get an answer without real world testing, as it depends on far too many factors. Things like application side caching and reuse for instance -if you are going to need that data again, you might as well send it to the app. For large amount of data, it is better to not ship it from the database to the application for the processing, as it ties up both the DB, the network connection and your application resources ( memory and cpu )

Answer (score 1):

Actually mix of both so that you have optimal IO and also optimal use of resources and index. You don't want too much data flowing over the wire which require full table scan. Choose some kind of paging mechanism and do rest on app side